# Laravel default blade behaviour

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In the blade views, if I echo an unset variable I get an error. So the usual answer to this problem is:

```
{{ isset($variable) ? $variable : '' }}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to make it the default behaviour for blade templates, where an unset variable would just display empty string.

Comment: fyi, short version: `{{ $variable ?? '' }}`

Comment: it is a cool one, but my thing is, there are many outputs to update this way. To change the default behavior would be better, and I would prefer it to be the default in my future projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simply:

```
{{ $variable ?? '' }}
```

But if you want to make this behavior default for all variables without explicitly using the `??` operator you should code blade compiler.

1. Extend the Blade Compiler:

```
namespace App\Extensions;

use Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler;

class CustomBladeCompiler extends BladeCompiler
{
    protected function compileEchoDefaults($value)
    {
        return preg_replace('/\{\{\s*(\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\s*\}\}/', '{{ $1 ?? \'\' }}', $value);
    }

    public function compileString($value)
    {
        $value = $this->compileEchoDefaults($value);
        return parent::compileString($value);
    }
}
```

2. AppServiceProvider:

```
use App\Extensions\CustomBladeCompiler;

public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('blade.compiler', function () {
        return new CustomBladeCompiler($this->app['files'], $this->app['config']['view.compiled']);
    });
}
```